# How do I fix NuGet Package Manager Console error "Signature specified is zero-sized"?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I've got a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and am getting the following message in the Package Manager Console:

> Signature specified is zero-sized. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131237)

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling NuGet Package Manager, but the issue remains.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there more detailed error message?

Comment: Repairing and reinstalling VS didn't work.  Ultimately I ended up rebuilding the machine completely to eliminate the issue.

Comment: It would have been nice for whomever down voted this question to have provided some comment for what was wrong with the question.  I'm not sure I could have provided more information that would have been relevant.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, this error often caused by the corrupted .NET Framework installation. You could use the .NET Framework Repair Tool from below link to repair .NET Framework installation on your machine.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2698555

Comment: Unfortunately, running that tool reported that it was unable to fix the problems.

Comment: If the tool could not fix the problems, I think you can repair your Visual Studio to repair the .NET Framework and if repair also doesn't work, I suggest you reinstall your Visual Studio 2015.